# FileReader unable to find the file in Java Project

Tags: java, file

I am developing a Java EE application on Mac OS using Tomcat 7 server.
My project structure looks like this -
[image]

Below is the function that I am using to read the JSON file - `20180507.json`

```
private void getCurrencyJSON(){
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        try 
        {
            System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsoluteFile());
            FileReader reader = new FileReader("/data/20180507.json");  
            //Read JSON file
            Object obj = jsonParser.parse(reader);
            JSONArray currencyList = (JSONArray) obj;
            System.out.println(currencyList);           

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (org.json.simple.parser.ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
```

This results in a `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /resources/20180507.json (No such file or directory)` exception. 
Also, `System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsoluteFile())` results in `/private/var/folders/0z/88rzgp7s4h3d18zzp4btcr2h3x133x/T/AppTranslocation/89F63404-971F-4AB6-9727-B1BD6E9F4A8D/d/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/.`

How do I read this file? Also, is there a resource from where I can learn more about how file paths work in Java?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not adding it to `resources` folder and read it from classpath on runtime?

Comment: If you really want to keep it in src folder then try`new FileReader("data/20180507.json"); ` . This would work.

Comment: @leopal Adding it under resources gives me the same error- java.io.FileNotFoundException: /resources/data/20180507.json (No such file or directory)

even though the file exists under resources > data

Comment: sure, because at runtime this relative path does not exist. At runtime, your path is where your IDE "runs", your tree structure is correct but this might be nested at runtime too. Maybe you should put it to ressources or an system fixed path like the user home or a temp dir

Comment: @ArchitArora I proposed to load it from classpath, `/resources/data/20180507.json` is still a relative path. Check [this](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/) for more.

Comment: have you try @ruhul suggestion  new FileReader("data/20180507.json")

Comment: Link: https://www.journaldev.com/848/java-file-path-absolute-canonical

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should store your data into resource folder.
like:

```
src
|__main
   |__java
   |  |__....
   |
   |__resources
      |__data
         |__20180507.json
```

After saving this:
you can try following code to load it from resource folder:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("data/20180507.json"));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Remember to use**:

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader("data/20180507.json");
```

instead of **"/data/20180507.json"** because this is the path for **"data"** folder inside the **root (/)** directory.

Also kindly try to Place your "data" directory inside the "resource" folder.
When building an application using eclipse the resource folder contents are place adjacent to the classes after compilation.

Either one of this should solve your issue.

Comment: What I said was also valid your class path referred to the folder inside the root directory and usually we place the raw assets files and folder inside the resource folder not just outside. if placed inside the resource folder then you can access it using relative path instead of absolute path.